# how to set dynamic time warping window adjustment?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, dynamic-programming

I am using a DTW (dynamic time warping) code. 
does anybody happen to know how should I set the size of adjustment window ? (global path constraint)

Answer (score 1):

cross validation

get some labeled data, set the warping window to zero, measure the leave one out accuracy

Then keep increasing the warping window size until the accuracy gets worse.

See fig 5 and 6 of the paper below

eamonn

Ratanamahatana, C. A. and Keogh. E. (2004). Everything you know about Dynamic Time Warping is Wrong. Third Workshop on Mining Temporal and Sequential Data, in conjunction with the Tenth ACM SIGKDD International Conference on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining (KDD-2004), August 22-25, 2004 - Seattle, WA
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/DTW_myths.pdf

Comment: so it depends on data. but what should I do in case dataset is so large that I cannot afford for this cross validation process ? (thanks, the paper is great)